# Missing artifact log4j:log4j:bundle:1.2.16 when using Maven in Eclipse simplistic example

Tags: eclipse, maven, log4j, dependency-management, m2e

I have created simple project from maven-archetype-quickstart under Eclipse Indigo, then I went to pom.xml gui editor and in dependencies tab added dependency on log4j-1.2.16 by search in appropriate dialog.

Now my pom.xml includes tags

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.16</version>
    <type>bundle</type>
</dependency>
```

But Eclipse underlines first `<dependency>` tag and says `Missing artifact log4j:log4j:bundle:1.2.16`.

Why?

The Maven plugin for Eclipse is m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse version 1.0.100.20110804-1717

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Remove

```
<type>bundle</type>
```

and it will be fine.

log4j:log4j is actually of type jar.

Comment: Why it was added by Eclipse? Is it an Eclipse plugin bug or something?

Comment: I guess maybe you selected the wrong one from the list (type bundle is for OSGi if I'm not mistaken). If you ommit the type tag it will default to jar which is the most common case.